# How to parse DateTime with Time between the dates?

Tags: java, java-time

I want to parse a date-time variant that has the time in between the dates. Why is the following not working?

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E L  d HH:mm:ss yyyy").parse("Tue Mar  1 01:29:47 2022")
```

Result:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Mar  1 01:29:47 2022' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: Your datetime is missing a month…

Comment: Added it meanwhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to make sure that

- you provide a specific `Locale` for abbreviated months and days of week
- you use the correct characters in the pattern of your `DateTimeFormatter`

A month of year is parsed using the character `M` in a pattern and you have to make sure the correct language is used and the amount of `M`s meets the requirements (e.g. `EEEE` will parse a full day of week, like `"Monday"`). That's ensurable by passing a `Locale` to the `DateTimeFormatter`. A pattern with a single `d` will parse days of month without leading zeros, while `dd` would require leading zeros to single-digit days of month.

Here's an example parsing two datetimes, one with a single-digit day of month and one

```java
DateTimeFormatter customDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy",
        Locale.ENGLISH
);
    
System.out.println( // parse a datetime with a two-digit day of month
        LocalDateTime.parse("Mon Mar 14 01:29:47 2022", customDtf)
);
System.out.println( // parse a datetime with a one-digit day of month
        LocalDateTime.parse("Tue Mar 1 01:29:47 2022", customDtf)
);
```

If you execute this sample code in a `main`, you'll get the following output:

```
2022-03-14T01:29:47
2022-03-01T01:29:47
```

Comment: That's a good explanation, and works! What would I have to change to support 2-digit days? eg 11 instead of 1? (unfortunately single-digit day of month are not input as `01`, but simply as `1`).